# Is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth ‘s state valid in session?

Tags: session, oauth, csrf

I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth to make integration with my company auth2.0 sso system.
my question is that dose this component need to be considered with load balace problems,such as session.
[OAuth2 10.12 CSRF] [state check] in this component is designed using session?

I dotnot know about this .